# Is adding virtual switch to Hyper-V safe over RDP with default settings?

Tags: networking, hyper-v-server-2012

I'm connected to a Windows Server 2012 R2 over RDP. Hyper-V feature is enabled and I have created a virtual machine. Now I need an external virtual switch so I can access the VM from outside.
I have two network adapters which are teamed up to a multiplexer and two public IPv4 are binded to this multiplexer adapter.
Is it safe (still have access to host over RDP) to add an external virtual switch with default settings?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean `is it safe?` - safe in what respect?

Comment: Safe means I still have access to server over RDP since a warning comes up when I press apply.

Comment: What's the warning? How about providing details so that we don't have to keep guessing as to what you're doing and what your concern is.

Comment: @joeqwerty: question updated. Warning screenshot added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the multiplexor NIC is the one your RDP'ing through, once you hit "yes", the OS will discard the adapters current config and make a new virtual NIC (shared by host and VM) with default DHCP settings (which is kinda weird to me, that you cant change to static on creation of the NIC in GUI) and try to obtain an IP for the new virtual NIC.

So, to my knowledge, unless you have DHCP set up accordingly on its location, you will loose connectivity permanently. But maybe Powershell can help you out with scripting creation of the virtual NIC and then setting the IP accordingly? The script would ofc have to be run on the remote host.